# Why is my for loop rewriting the list of names I'm cycling through?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have list of the column names 'sample_names' for a pandas dataframe. I'm passing a function 'lambdas' through every column in my dataframe using a for loop, which works OK. However the for loop is also re-writing the list of column names 'sample_names' so that the list only contains the last sample name rather than all of the sample names. Not sure why this is happening?

The list of sample_names has this form: ['GMBP02Z1-1', 'GMBP02Z1-2', 'GMBP02Z2-1', 'GMBP02Z2-2',...]

and the output lambda_values this form:[array([  3.74993618, -44.14515681, -35.77677525, 299.47783486]), array([  3.71842561, -43.99570425, -38.938825  , 153.75523515]), array([   3.31301049, ....]

```
for i in sample_names:
    sample_names = i
    params = OP_constants(subset_radii, degree=4)
    lambda_values.append(lambdas(np.log(subset_y2[sample_names]), subset_radii, params = params, degree = 4))
print(lambda_values)
```

Comment: Impossible to say with no more than you've posted.

Comment: `sample_names = i` - there's your problem. If that's not it, you need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list object 'sample_names' exists outside your loop.  The first line in your loop is always:

> sample_names = i

So at the start of every loop you've revised the sample_names object to just be whatever the most recent string in your 'sample_names' list is.  After the final loop that is the last item in sample_names.

Perhaps changing the first line in your loop (and all the subsequent references to sample_names within the loop) to:

> sample_name = i

would accomplish what you are intending?

Comment: Ah ok, I understand that better now, your change fixes the issue, thank you for your help!